# Java Concurrency in Practice: BoundedExecutor implementation

Tags: java, exception, concurrency, executor

This is the implementation of the BoundedExecutor class in the Java Concurrency in Practice book:

```
public class BoundedExecutor {
    private final Executor exec;
    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    public BoundedExecutor(Executor exec, int bound) {
        this.exec = exec;
        this.semaphore = new Semaphore(bound);
    }

    public void submitTask(final Runnable command) throws InterruptedException {
        semaphore.acquire();

        try {
            exec.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        command.run();
                    } finally {
                        semaphore.release();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a reason why the RejectedExecutionException is being caught instead of letting it propagate further? In this case, if the task is rejected, whoever submits the task will be none the wiser.

Isn't is better to just replace the catch-block with a finally-block?

This is my implementation of a BoundedExecutor that accepts a Callable instead of a Runnable:

```
public class BoundedExecutor {
    private final ExecutorService exec; 
    private final Semaphore semaphore; 

    public BoundedExecutor(ExecutorService exec, int bound) { 
        this.exec = exec; 
        this.semaphore = new Semaphore(bound); 
    } 

    public <V> Future<V> submitTask(final Callable<V> command) throws InterruptedException { 
        semaphore.acquire(); 

        try { 
            return exec.submit(new Callable<V>() {
                @Override public V call() throws Exception { 
                    try { 
                        return command.call();
                    } finally { 
                        semaphore.release(); 
                    } 
                } 
            });
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) { 
            semaphore.release();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it a correct implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see with changing the catch to a finally is that, in the event that the task does get submitted and a RejectedExecutionException is not thrown, you will end up releasing the semaphore twice instead of just once.  If you want to propagate the exception in the catch block version, you can simply add `throw e;` after releasing the semaphore.

Comment: Right! I've adjusted my version of the BoundedExecutor above. Does it work correctly now?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your solution is incorrect. The call `exec.submit(Callable task)` gives the client a reference to a Future, the invocation of get() on this Future gives the user either the desired result or the exception (CancellationException, ExecutionException et-all).

So wrapping exec.submit in a try catch block will not help and the original implementation of wrapping the execute call in a try catch block is the correct one.

Alternatively, you could wrap the user's command in a future task rather than a callable and in your FutureTask override the done method to invoke semaphore.release().

Comment: I know what a Future is. Could you please elaborate on why my BoundedExecutor doesn't work?

Comment: Well there were reasons I had thought of; can't seem to recollect all. 1) you are returning  a future, say the user cancels the future, this executor doesn't seem to handle it. I can't seem to recollect anything more right now but I am updating my answer to suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: The semaphore is released in the finally-block when when I call `cancel(true)` on my Future for an interruptible task.

Comment: precisely why should probably consider my suggestion as the semaphore release is already scattered to three places. other than that, you should give this one a try, best of luck!!