# jms persistent messages and order of messages obtained

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

What i need:
 1. Send messages through jms.
 2. Have messages persisted so that if not handled from client and server restarts client gets the message on server restart.
 3. Messages should be received from client in the same order as these messages have been sent.
 4. Have multiple consumers in the queue so as to scale and handle different messages in parallel.

What i did:
I use active mq and have the following spring configuration

```
<bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="destination"/>
</bean>

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="deliveryMode" value="2"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="destination"/>
</bean>

<bean id="messageListener" class="InternalNotificationJMSConsumer"/>

<jms:listener-container connection-factory="pooledConnectionFactory" acknowledge="client" destination-type="queue" concurrency="5-10" container-type="simple"  cache="none" client-id="client1" prefetch="1">
      <jms:listener destination="destination" ref="messageListener" method="onMessage"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

So i have my destination and my connection pool. Then i create a spring jmstemplate and start sending messages

```
template.send(new MessageCreator() {
  public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
    return session.createObjectMessage(message);
  }
});
```

Then i have the receiver as follows:

```
@Component
public class JMSConsumer implements MessageListener {

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
      ....
     }
   }
```

My problems:

a. Messages using this configuration are not received in order. This makes sence given the xsd comment in listener-container.concurency: "keep concurrency limited to 1 in case of a topic listener or if message ordering is important;". So question is how/if i can keep order but have multiple consumers.

b. message acknowledgement. What i need is that after message has been processed, onMessage returns, only then message is considered as acknowledged and not re-transmited. I have no transactionmanager in terms that i am not inside any application server and wish to avoid this if possible. i only need to acknowledge messages my self. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are consuming messages in parallel, then due to the nature of threading there can never be a guarantee that they will be completed in exactly the order they were sent in - only that they will be handed off to consumers in order. If there are only certain messages that absolutely, positively must be ordered (usually related to a transaction/account), you can use [Message Groups](https://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html) feature to associate groups with consumers - a kind of sticky load balancing.

Acknowledging messages by yourself is most definitely possible, but probably not needed. The `MessageListenerContainer` has a `acknowledge` attribute which if set to `transacted` will result in the message only being acknowledged as consumed once the `MessageListener` has completed executing, without an exception being thrown. No transaction manager necessary (though Spring's `PlatformTransactionManager` doesn't need any particular container if you did want to use one).

If you definitely want to acknowledge messages yourself, set `acknowledge` to `client`, and call `message.acknowledge()` when your message has completed successfully. If the listener completes without this being called, the message will be sent to a DLQ (default) or redelivered.

Comment: "only that they will be handed off to consumers in order."--> Ok, this is what i care about, then the processing order is another thing. So how can i ensure that the messages will be handed over to consumers in order? Through MessageGroups?

About message.acknowledge(), this is what i tried and did not work, i will give it a try with transacted as it sounds promising

Comment: The handoff is always done in order by ActiveMQ in a round-robin fashion between consumers. There is a mechanism called a prefetch buffer on the consumer side that acts as a cache so that you don't have to ask the broker for more messages constantly - it is set by default to 1000 messages per queue. Depending on arrival time, a consumer may fill up that buffer before the next consumer arrives. Set it via `prefetch="1"` on the `jms:listener-container` to get a fair distribution of messages.

Comment: First of all Thank you Jake, I needed to say it as your responses are fast and up to the point. That said, please check my code above. Already done so and have set prefetch="1". I understand what you say and this was my understanding as well but this is not what i see in my code.

Comment: <continuation from my above comment due to character limit...> Not sure if this comes from from activemq/spring code or the messages that get out of order are persisted in kahadb first as not possible at that moment to be handled and then when available thread exists to receive messages these come back to the surface. I will remove persistency and re-check if messages are still out of order and comment again on this finding. Perhaps it is on kahadb level that the problem exists...and if so some other configuration to give priority to persisted messages may be needed

Comment: How are you checking whether messages are out of order?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But was away from computer due to personal reasons.
simple: i am sending ObjectMessage wich contain inside it a serializable proprietary pojo. Within this object i have an int propery named counter which when i send messages from a single threaded producer i increment this counter by one with every message i send. The consumer on the other hand, prints this counter in the console.

Comment: And with a single thread consuming, you are seeing the messages coming out of order?

Comment: No with single thread consuming i see messages arive in order. 
with many threads i see it out of order.
I found a solution for multiple consumption of messages and these come in order. It regards escaping from jms configuration and using simple java code. will post my answer

Comment: When you consume from multiple consumers, the messages will arrive in order to each consumer. Which message id gets printed first is non-deterministic due to the threading between the two consumers. A message stream `1:2:3:4` might get consumed by consumer A as `1:3` and consumer B as `2:4`. When printed, it's entirely probable that they might be `2:1:3:4`. This is because each consumer is a thread with its own prefetch buffer. To really check whether they're "out of order" as you claim, prepend the thread name to the output. You'll find they're not out of order at all.

Comment: Found the answer to what i was trying to succeed. I posted it above for others to use.
I mark Jake's answer as correct since he answered part of my original question and helped a lot.

Comment: "Which msg id gets printed 1st is non-deterministic due to the threading.." Hm, i am confused now, yes, having multiple threads means that things become more complex.In my original idea to have concurency (concurent=10),i was thinking we have something like 10 message listeners. Since every message listener prints imidiatelly the received message and then takes 10'' break (Thread.sleep(10000)), 1st produced message should be printed first (from 1st message listener), 2nd message 2nd && so on.This for sure does not happen. What i found is a nasty work around but did not find something better.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the answer to my problem.

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="pooledConnectionFactory" acknowledge="client" destination-type="queue" concurrency="5-10" container-type="simple"  cache="none" prefetch="1">
      <jms:listener destination="destination" ref="messageListener" method="onMessage"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

Then on message listener implementation:
BlockingExecutor executor = new BlockingExecutor(5); //number of concurent massages to be consumed

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
....
executor.submitTask(new MessageDispatchCommand((ObjectMessage) message));
....
```

}

```
class MessageDispatchCommand implements Runnable {
  private ObjectMessage message;

  public MessageDispatchCommand (final ObjectMessage message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      Serializable msg = message.getObject();
      handle message here
     }....
}
```

BlockingExecutor  code can be found from here:
    [Java Concurrency in Practice: BoundedExecutor implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374578/java-concurrency-in-practice-boundedexecutor-implementation)

Simply put. i have only one jms message listener since this keeps message order correct.
Then i create runnable commands to get messages and handle them (here is the time consuming job done but it is made inside different threads).
Since i use a boundedexecutor when all message handling threads have been exausted, onMessage blocks and thus subsequent messages are simply persisted untill a thread of the bounded executor becomes free again.